# Pre-deployed implementation contracts for proxy pattern

Tags: contract-deployment, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

I'm planning to deploy a few upgradeable OpenZeppelin contracts as UUPS proxies. To save money, I would like to find some existing implementation contracts that are already deployed, so I just have to deploy proxy contracts that point to them. Is this safe, and if so, what is a good way to go about finding implementation contracts? Does openzeppelin keep a list of deployments anywhere (if not maybe they should?)? Otherwise could I use etherscan to find matching binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that works just fine if the binaries match, even better if you trust the company underlying that implementation (like OZ).  But no list, if you want a specific reference implementation I'd just ask (here or them) for the specific one/ most up to date one to use. Just be sure to initialize the variables properly!